# Saving Scheduled Reports directly onto my server

Tags: reports-api

Does anyone know how or if possible, to schedule a report to save automatically onto a mapped path on my server?

In essence, we use Qlik Sense requires a manual upload of data from a folder on our server. I cant seem to find a way via Salesforce which could allow this?

Comment: Hi Nick, welcome to SFSE! Please visit the [help] and read [ask]. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Are you able to process inbound emails somewhere on your external server?